# Upgrading google maps api with mapstraction in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps-api-3, mapstraction

I'm trying to upgrade an app into Rails 3. The app requires a map that can be edited and it has been using google maps and mapstraction. When I upgraded to rails 3 the map stopped showing up and I figured that's because it needed to be updated from google maps api v2 to v3.

I've been trying to use this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/v2tov3) to upgrade it but because the app is using mapstraction I've been having difficulty getting it to work.

Initially, this was in the html:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=2&key=<%= GOOGLE_MAPS_KEY %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/mapstraction/mxn.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/mapstraction/mxn.core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/mapstraction/mxn.google.core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And the maps.js was as follows:

```
var Map = function() {
    this.init()
}

$.extend(Map.prototype, {
    m : false,
    init: function() {
        this.m = new mxn.Mapstraction('mapdiv', 'googlev3')
        this.m.addControls({pan: true, zoom: 'large', map_type: false})
        // this.m.enableScrollWheelZoom()
        this.m.setMapType(3)
        return this.m
    },
    addPoint: function(lat, lng, html) {
        var myPoint = new mxn.LatLonPoint(lat, lng);
        var marker = new mxn.Marker(myPoint);
        marker.setInfoBubble(html);
        this.m.addMarker(marker);
    },
    setCenterAndZoom: function(center, zoom) {
        this.m.setCenterAndZoom(center, zoom)
    },
    boundingBox: function(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
        var zoom = this.m.getZoomLevelForBoundingBox(new mxn.BoundingBox(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2))
        var centerlng = (lon1 + lon2) / 2
        var centerlat = (lat1 + lat2) / 2
        var myPoint = new mxn.LatLonPoint(centerlat, centerlng);
        this.m.setCenterAndZoom(myPoint, zoom)
    },
    addPointToLine: function(lat, lng, line, html, length) {
        var point = new mxn.LatLonPoint(lat, lng)
        line.points.push(point);
        var i = line.points.length
        var num = 100
        if (i == 1) {
            m.addPoint(lat, lng, html)
        }
    },
    addUser: function(lat, lng, avatar, html) {
        var marker = new mxn.Marker(new mxn.LatLonPoint(lat, lng));
        marker.setInfoBubble(html);
        marker.setIcon(avatar);
        marker.setIconSize([30,30])
        m.m.addMarker(marker);
    }
});
```

I tried changing the html to this (based on the upgrade tutorial and the tutorial from mapstraction):

```
<script src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://mapstraction.com/mxn/build/latest/mxn.js?(googlev3)" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But when that didn't make a difference I tried to remove mapstraction and change the maps.js to the following:

```
var Map = function() {
    this.init()
}

$.extend(Map.prototype, {
    m : false,
    init: function() {
        this.m = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapdiv'), {zoom: 13, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID});
        // this.m.addControls({pan: true, zoom: 'large', map_type: false})
        // this.m.enableScrollWheelZoom()
        // this.m.setMapType(3)
        return this.m
    },
    addPoint: function(lat, lng, html) {
        var myPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker(myPoint);
        marker.setInfoBubble(html);
        this.m.addMarker(marker);
    },
    setCenterAndZoom: function(center, zoom) {
        this.m.setCenterAndZoom(center, zoom)
    },
    boundingBox: function(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
        var zoom = this.m.getZoomLevelForBoundingBox(new google.maps.LatLonAltBox(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2))
        var centerlng = (lon1 + lon2) / 2
        var centerlat = (lat1 + lat2) / 2
        var myPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(centerlat, centerlng);
        this.m.setCenterAndZoom(myPoint, zoom)
    },
    addPointToLine: function(lat, lng, line, html, length) {
        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng)
        line.points.push(point);
        var i = line.points.length
        var num = 100
        if (i == 1) {
            m.addPoint(lat, lng, html)
        }
    },
    addUser: function(lat, lng, avatar, html) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng));
        marker.setInfoBubble(html);
        marker.setIcon(avatar);
        marker.setIconSize([30,30])
        m.m.addMarker(marker);
    }
});
```

But still nothing...does anyone have any idea how I can get the map to display?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. as it seems your code uses jQuery(`$.extend`), did you include jQuery?
2. all the method you've defined are methods of `Map`  but you try to call these methods for `Map.m`(which is a `google.map.Map`-instance and doesn't have such methods)
3. I don't see where you create the `Map`-instance(I mean your "class", not the `google.maps.Map`) at all
4. a `google.maps.Map` requires a `center`-property which is not present(at least not when you create the `google.maps.Map`-instance in `Map.init()`)