# Using Mapstraction and Google maps API - map not showing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps-api-3, mapstraction

I'm trying to upgrade a RoR app that uses mapstraction and google maps api, but I can't seem to get the map to show...I already posted a question with the code from that app here but haven't got an answer yet:

[Upgrading google maps api with mapstraction in Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30714265/upgrading-google-maps-api-with-mapstraction-in-rails-3)

Because I still can't get that to work I created a test app and tried to get mapstraction working with the google maps api from scratch to see if I can replicate the issue and therefore fix it....but I still can't seem to get this to work.

In html of the test app I have:

```
<DOCTYPE! HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://mapstraction.com/mxn/build/latest/mxn.js?(googlev3)" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
    #map {
      height: 100px;
    }
    </style>
   </head>
   <body>
   <div id="map"></div>

   <script type="text/javascript">
    var map = new mxn.Mapstraction('map', 'googlev3');
    var latlon = new mxn.LatLonPoint(39.74,-104.98);
    map.setCenterAndZoom(latlon, 10);
   </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This code is based on the tutorial for mapstraction that can be found [here](http://mapstraction.com/tutorial).

The map is still not showing when I run this code, however it is showing "Map data  Terms of Use" at the bottom of the div, as if the map is there...

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here? I'm really stuck... :(

Comment: your code works for me.

Comment: Hmm, ok I've also managed to get it working now by removing some css that had been running on it...unfortunately this still doesn't fix my original problem :(

Comment: Are turbolinks enabled? They can cause such problems.

Comment: The app is in Rails 3.0 so shouldn't be using turbolinks should it?

Answer (score 0):

So by playing around with some of the css I found out that the map hadn't been showing because I had the div display style set to inline-block...this still takes me back to square one with my original problem ([Upgrading google maps api with mapstraction in Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30714265/upgrading-google-maps-api-with-mapstraction-in-rails-3)) but at least I know mapstraction and google maps is working :)